# Compare IDs within groups of groups - Whats wrong with my grouping or looping?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement, pandas-groupby

I want to compare time intervals in my dataset (5 seconds) and apply conditional formatting to another grouping of tables in order to classify the IDsinto group sizes. My code looks like this:

```
mindist = 100
maxdist = 200

grouped1 = result1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='date', freq="5S"))

group = []

for i, groups1 in grouped1:
    for g, tables1 in groups1.groupby('table'):

        for d1,d2 in zip(tables1.nnDist1,tables1.nnDist2):
            if tables1.id.nunique() > 2 and d1 < mindist and d2 < maxdist:
                group.append(2)
            elif tables1.id.nunique() == 2 and d1 < mindist and d2 > maxdist:
                group.append(1)
            elif tables1.id.nunique() < 2:
                group.append(0)
            else:
                group.append(9)

result1['gs_pred'] = group
```

It basically does what I want. It groups the dataset into time bunches of 5 seconds, furtherly groups them into tables, and compares each table of whether there are more than 1 unique IDs and based on distances, it classifies them into 0=alone, 1=pair, 2= group.

My problem is that sometimes, even tho the conditions are met, it wrongly classifies my data.

For instance group "table 5":

```
id      nnDist1             nnDist2             table   zone    pred_gs   date
3479.0  55.06369039574004   68.07613385026653   Table5  Zone2   0         2019-10-09 15:30:41.431
3477.0  55.06369039574004   99.14655818534048   Table5  Zone2   0         2019-10-09 15:30:41.431
3476.0  38.02749005658375   80.28754573408989   Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:41.431
3473.0  38.02749005658375   68.07613385026653   Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:41.431
3473.0  38.07413820430603   70.09457896299827   Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:43.831
3479.0  53.91660226686884   70.09457896299827   Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:43.831
3477.0  53.91660226686884   100.09240730444223  Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:43.831
3476.0  38.07413820430603   80.2626314046803    Table5  Zone2   2         2019-10-09 15:30:43.831
```

Even tho ID 3479 amd 3477 are within the same group as the others, and the distances are below the thresholds, why does it classify those IDs to 0=sitting alone?

I hope anyone has an idea? What am I doing wrong here with my grouping?
Help is very appreciated!

My data set looks like this:

```
Out[17]: 
                        date      id     nnDist1     nnDist2   table
0    2019-10-09 00:00:01.405  2948.0  118.422971         NaN  Table3
1    2019-10-09 00:00:01.405  2958.0  118.422971         NaN  Table1
2    2019-10-09 00:00:03.965  2948.0  118.169370         NaN  Table3
3    2019-10-09 00:00:03.965  2958.0  118.169370         NaN  Table1
4    2019-10-09 00:00:06.445  2948.0  112.258630         NaN  Table3
5    2019-10-09 00:00:06.445  2958.0  112.258630         NaN  Table1
6    2019-10-09 00:00:08.925  2948.0  113.362251         NaN  Table3
7    2019-10-09 00:00:08.925  2958.0  113.362251         NaN  Table1
8    2019-10-09 00:00:11.405  2964.0  233.294578  271.488950  Table4
9    2019-10-09 00:00:11.405  2948.0  115.801598  271.488950  Table3
10   2019-10-09 00:00:11.405  2958.0  115.801598  233.294578  Table1
11   2019-10-09 00:00:13.965  2958.0  114.227842         NaN  Table1
12   2019-10-09 00:00:13.965  2948.0  114.227842         NaN  Table3
13   2019-10-09 00:00:16.445  2948.0  108.701426         NaN  Table3
14   2019-10-09 00:00:16.445  2958.0  108.701426         NaN  Table1
15   2019-10-09 00:00:18.925  2948.0  114.926237         NaN  Table3
16   2019-10-09 00:00:18.925  2958.0  114.926237         NaN  Table1
17   2019-10-09 00:00:21.405  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
18   2019-10-09 00:00:23.885  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
19   2019-10-09 00:00:26.445  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
20   2019-10-09 00:00:28.925  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
21   2019-10-09 00:00:31.405  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
22   2019-10-09 00:00:33.965  2965.0  112.442697         NaN  Table2
23   2019-10-09 00:00:33.965  2958.0  112.442697         NaN  Table1
24   2019-10-09 00:00:36.445  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
25   2019-10-09 00:00:38.925  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
26   2019-10-09 00:00:41.405  2958.0         NaN         NaN  Table1
27   2019-10-09 00:00:43.966  2958.0  229.792167         NaN  Table1
28   2019-10-09 00:00:43.966  2964.0  229.792167         NaN  Table4
29   2019-10-09 00:00:46.446  2948.0  111.665796         NaN  Table3
                     ...     ...         ...         ...     ...
9970 2019-10-09 15:30:33.911  3447.0  118.111007  119.913677  Table7
9971 2019-10-09 15:30:33.911  3390.0  176.425168  178.949183  Table3
9972 2019-10-09 15:30:33.911  3495.0   73.363547  103.771672  Table4
9973 2019-10-09 15:30:33.911  3479.0   53.094632   69.082849  Table5
9974 2019-10-09 15:30:33.911  3476.0   49.912824   73.363547  Table5
9975 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3473.0   43.400922   70.030351  Table5
9976 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3479.0   53.610074   70.030351  Table5
9977 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3477.0   53.610074   99.107063  Table5
9978 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3447.0  113.468233  118.808628  Table7
9979 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3390.0  176.123934  183.319639  Table3
9980 2019-10-09 15:30:36.391  3476.0   43.400922   80.874532  Table5
9981 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3473.0   38.053778   68.235548  Table5
9982 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3479.0   53.028294   68.235548  Table5
9983 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3477.0   53.028294  101.133575  Table5
9984 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3447.0  116.514420  118.551930  Table7
9985 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3390.0  179.093160  194.106053  Table3
9986 2019-10-09 15:30:38.951  3476.0   38.053778   81.731267  Table5
9987 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3479.0   55.063690   68.076134  Table5
9988 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3477.0   55.063690   99.146558  Table5
9989 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3447.0  115.530126  118.474681  Table7
9990 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3390.0  168.371643  185.809069  Table3
9991 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3476.0   38.027490   80.287546  Table5
9992 2019-10-09 15:30:41.431  3473.0   38.027490   68.076134  Table5
9993 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3473.0   38.074138   70.094579  Table5
9994 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3479.0   53.916602   70.094579  Table5
9995 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3477.0   53.916602  100.092407  Table5
9996 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3476.0   38.074138   80.262631  Table5
9997 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3390.0  174.818449  188.241866  Table3
9998 2019-10-09 15:30:43.831  3447.0  110.936739  114.397596  Table7
9999 2019-10-09 15:30:43.911  3390.0  174.599656  189.973709  Table3
```

Comment: Interesting you did not receive this error: `AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'TimeGrouper'` as `TimeGrouper` has been deprecated for `Grouper`.

Comment: I might have a older version of python?! But the problem is in the grouping i believe..

Comment: Curious, what happens if your sort your data frame: `result1 = result1.sort_values(['date', 'table']).reset_index(drop=True)`? Do you generate desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid a looped solution as `groupby` runs `sort=True` but you assign by order of original data frame. Additionally, you are checking against scalar values iteratively and not by Series with vectorization.

Instead, consider a [**`groupby().apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) approach with either [**`np.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [**`np.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally assign *gs_pred* column. With this approach you keep all group and underlying values intact:

```
def calc_groups(g):
    # LOGICAL CONDITIONS
    cond1 = (g['id'].nunique() >  2) & (g['nnDist1'] < mindist) & (g['nnDist2'] < maxdist)
    cond2 = (g['id'].nunique() == 2) & (g['nnDist1'] < mindist) & (g['nnDist2'] > maxdist)
    cond3 = (g['id'].nunique() <  2)

    # NUMPY SELECT APPROACH
    g['gs_pred2'] = np.select([cond1, cond2, cond3], [2, 1, 0], default=9)

    # NUMPY WHERE APPROACH  
    g['gs_pred3'] = np.where(cond1, 2,
                             np.where(cond2, 1,
                                      np.where(cond3, 0, 9)
                             )
                    )
    return g

# RUN ASSIGNMENT BY GROUP(S)
result1 = (result1.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq="5S"), 'table'], as_index=False)
                  .apply(calc_groups))
```

Comment: you nailed it Parfait, thank you so much! It is great learning this way.